# Getting error while installing pandas on Cygwin (on 64bit windows7 machine)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, cygwin

Following is the error I am getting.

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-d                  ev|python-devel.
_configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’
 int exp (void);
     ^~~
_configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
_configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the proper `python3*-devel` package:

```
$ cygcheck -l python36-devel |grep "Python.h"
/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h

$ cygcheck -l python38-devel |grep "Python.h"
/usr/include/python3.8/Python.h
```

Answer (score 0):

Best is to install Mobaxterm which comes with latest version of cygwin and then run following commands.

```
apt-get install python3-pip
```

which will install both Python3 and pip3 and all dependencies.

Then run

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Worked for me.

Comment: and that is wrong as the devel package will NOT be pulled.